# OneTimesetup is getting invoked for each Test,I thought OneTimesetup is like BeforeSuite,TestNG annotation

Tags: c#, nunit, winium

In Nunit C# Im trying to open the application only once and make modification to it, for example i created this demo of Notepad application. In my real time project,i just have to log in to the application just once and execute all 100 test cases and only then close the Desktop application. Kindly tell me what am i doing wrong here,thanks a lot! Btw,im new to C#

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Notepad
{ }
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class BaseClass

    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void AssemblyInitalize()
        {
            var dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dc.SetCapability("app", @"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9999"), dc);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public static void oneTearDown()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Close")).Click();

        }
    }
```

---First Test---

```
namespace Notepad
{    [TestFixture]
    public class Notepad2:BaseClass
    {

        [Test]
     public void test2()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("15")).SendKeys("My Teacher ");
        }

    }
}
```

---- Second Test Class ----

```
 using NUnit.Framework;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;

    namespace Notepad 
    {    [TestFixture]
      public  class NoteTest : BaseClass

        {


            [Test]
            public void Test()
            {

                driver.FindElement(By.Id("15")).SendKeys("...is Coming now");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding `SetUpFixture`, the first answer is incorrect.

`SetUpFixture` works exactly the same way as it has always worked. If you have a `SetUpFixture`, it's `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown` methods will run once **for all the fixtures** under the same namespace.

On the other hand, inside a `TestFixture` the `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown` methods run just once **for the fixture itself**.

In other words, the methods run "one time" within the particular scope in which they are used, namespace or fixture.

The problem is that you are using the same class as **both** a `SetUpFixture` and as the base class for all your `TestFixtures`. That means if you have `n` test fixtures, it will run `n + 1` times! That's what you are seeing.

`SetUpFixtures` do not (have never had) anything to do with fixture inheritance. You should **either** make your class a `SetUpFixture` or a `TestFixture` base class. If, for whatever reason, you need both, then use two classes. In this case, you need only the `SetUpFixture`, without the inheritance.

When to inherit from a base class: When you want the same code to execute many times, once for each fixture. Note that your base class, when used for one-time setup and teardown in this way, should normally **not** be marked as a TestFixture.

When to use a SetUpFixture: When you want some code to execute only once, before every any fixture runs and again once after all the fixtures have run.

In your example, you are using a SetUpFixture to control the timing of the initialization. You are using inheritance to allow you to share the driver. Problem is that the OneTimeSetUp in the base class is actually part of **each** test fixture and you don't want that.

I'd be concerned about a hundred or so tests all using the same driver. I've seen some people use one driver per **test** and others one driver per **fixture_. Using one for __everything** implies that you are being extraordinarily careful that each test cleans up after itself and restores the driver to the same state. I doubt that's possible.

However, as an exercise, here is how to do it if you really want to:
1. Have a base class with nothing but the driver member.
2. Derive the SetUpFixture from the base class and create / destroy the driver there.
3. Derive the TestFixtures from the same base class. They use but don't change the driver.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to educate me much appreciated. :) Even when  i made the BaseClass as a TestFixture, im  still unable to call the tests which are in the the different classes. 
 Order is like this 1)OneTimeSetup 2)DerivedTestClass 3) OneTimeTeardown for every test case. Only when i put all test cases inside the same class it seems to be working in order as expected.   which is 
1) OneTimeSetup 2)all test cases  and then 3) OneTimeTeardown. All i want is to open the application just once and run all test cases ONLY then close the application. how can i do it? thanks once again.

Comment: As I wrote "in this case you need only the SetUpFixture, without the inheritance". I'll add a bit more to the answer...

Comment: Let's try this... __why__ do you want all your fixtures to use the same driver? I would be concerned that one test could malfunction in a way to break all the other tests.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. SetUpFixture without inheritance, how the driver of the test cases will get initialize, it will throw a null object reference,wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes you're right, but Company asked me  to log into the application just once and execute all test cases then close the application. What would you suggest, im open to the good advice as im new to writing the test cases in c#. I quite welcome your advice.

Comment: Im using SetUpfixture without the inheritance and using a constructor instead,public Notepad2(){ driver = BaseClass.driver;  } to initialize the webDriver. and using Notepad2 as a baseClass.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, [OneTimeSetup](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute) is called once before all tests in a TestFixture. Your example has two fixtures, so the set up is called twice. You need to have all your tests in the same Fixture.

This behaviour is different to the old [Setup] on [SetupFixture](http://nunit.org/docs/2.6.4/setupFixture.html) attribute, which ran once for all tests in a namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, how can i put them in the same Fixture, do i 've to bunk all test cases in the same class?

Comment: or Make the baseClass as a TestFixture and extend all the test cases.

Comment: I just now tried by making a BaseClass a TestFixture and extend two test cases, removed  the TestFixture attribute from the both tests, still the Notepad is opening twice and tearing down twice. its working only when i  put thetest cases inside the same class i.e Base Class.
Order is like this 1)OneTimeSetup 2)DerivedTestClass 3) OneTimeTeardown for every test case. 
But when test cases are in the same class i.e BaseClass,  oneTimeSetup and OneTimeTearDown occurring only once before and after all the test cases respectively.

Comment: It's quite normal to have all the tests that rely on one setup in the same class, even if there are 100 of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, test cases are not really small, each test case as you may already know containing more than 50 steps at least. The code will be too lengthy and would become unreadable and very difficult to debug.