# How to run the method only once in NUnit C#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am pretty new to C# and have always been a Java person. In Java selenium, this can be achieve by using the @BeforeSuite annotations. Initially, I thought it can be achieved by using the [OneTimeSetUp] annotations but it's not. When I am inheriting the Parent class to the child class, the [OneTimeSetUp] mentioned in the Parent class is getting called multiple times.

My requirement is that once the execution starts, I want to create a folder with the Unique ID and put the report in that folder. I have all the code for the same in the method but that is getting called multiple times which is causing the script to fail.

I tried searching a lot and I saw that people are recommending using [SetUpFixture] for the same. I tried using that as well but it is also not working for me. Am I missing something? Here is my code

My Parent Class:-

```
namespace Core.Framework.Controls
{
 [SetUpFixture]
 public class Controls
 {
    private string Browsername { get; set; }
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void BeforeSuite()
    {
       //Create Unique Folder
    }
```

Child1 Class:-

```
namespace Core
{
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class UnitTest1 : Controls
{

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(Controls), "BrowsersToRunWith")]
    public void Bing(String browser)
    {
        SetUp(browser);
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(_controls);
        class1.LaunchURL("http://bing.com");
        class1.EnterTextInBing("Parallel Execution using C#");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
  }
```

Child2 Class:-

```
namespace Core
{
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class UnitTest2 : Controls
{
  
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(Controls), "BrowsersToRunWith")]
    public void Google(String browser)
    {
        SetUp(browser);
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(_controls);
        class1.LaunchURL("http://google.com");
    }
  }
```

}

Updated the project structure as per @Charlie suggestion

```
 Base Class 
     • Setup Fixture 
     • No TestFixture 
     • One Time Setup 
     • One Time Tear Down 

  Parent Class : Base Class 
     • No TestFixture 
     • Set Up 
         o Driver initialization 
     • Tear Down 
         o Driver Quit 

 Child Class1:Parent Class 
     • Test Fixture 
     • Test Method 
         o Getting the driver instance from Parent class and testing the application 

  Child Class2:Parent Class 
     • Test Fixture 
     • Test Method 
         o Getting the driver instance from Parent class and testing the application –
```

Base Class Image

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneTimesetup is getting invoked for each Test,I thought OneTimesetup is like BeforeSuite,TestNG annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465501/onetimesetup-is-getting-invoked-for-each-test-i-thought-onetimesetup-is-like-bef)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and searching for the answer but I did try that solution with the approach given by @Charlie but that is also not working. Here is what I did

Base Class - I kept my SetUpFixture with OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTear down here

Controller  Inheriting Base Class - I kept my SetUp and tear down here

Test Clasess - Inheriting Controller - Only TestFixture and no SetUp or OneTimeSetup here

Still, it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there! I'll explain...

`SetUp` methods run for every test case. `OneTimeSetUp` methods run only once... but once per what?

When they are in a `TestFixture` they run once for the fixture. They take on the role of what was formerly called *TestFixtureSetUp* in older versions of NUnit. When you use a base fixture, an inherited `OneTimeSetUp` becomes part of each fixture, which inherits from the base.

So that's why your first attempts didn't work.

Creating a `SetUpFixture` is the solution, as you were told. A `SetUpFixture` contains `OneTimeSetUp` methods, which a run once per namespace or once for the entire assembly, depending on whether or not the fixture is defined within a namespace.

So, the `SetUpFixture` you created would run once for each execution of tests in the `Core.Framework.Controls` namespace. That's a good way to do it if you have tests in other namespaces, which don't need that setup.

So why is your `OneTimeSetUp` running for each fixture? If you watch closely in the debugger, or add some writes to it, you will probably see that it is actually running n + 1 times, where n is the number of fixtures!

By inheriting from your `SetUpFixture`, you have made it part of each `TestFixture` in addition to its function as a (one-time) `SetUpFixture`. You should simply stop using inheritance here.

When I created `SetUpFixture`, it never occurred to me that someone might inherit from it. The docs definitely don't suggest that and it didn't come up until recently, when I've now seen a few people doing it. If you found any article out there that suggests to do it that way, please let the author know it's not correct!

Comment: Thanks, Charlie for such a detailed explanation. We(mostly automation folks from Selenium) are using inheritance is because it helps us to initialize a new driver against each method (we use SetUp for the same) in the base class and the child class can use that driver instance to test the application on different browsers. This is how we design our automation framework.

Removing inheritance may help me in using the method [OneTimeSetUp] only once but that will change how our automation framework works. Any other solution which you suggest?  Thanks

Comment: You don't have to change anything else... just the SetUpFixture. You can still have a base class, from which all the TestFixtures inherit, but it should be separate because SetUpFixture is not intended to be inherited... at least not in the way you are doing it.

Comment: BTW, I added a warning note to the docs for SetUpFixture.

Comment: Hi @Charlie, I tried the same setup but still, it is not working for me. My OneTimesetup code is being call multiple times. I have added my structurein the comment below. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

I tried keeping the Base class separate from the Parent class but in that case, the OneTimeMethod is not getting called even for 1 time.

Comment: Base Class
• Setup Fixture
• No TestFixture
• One Time Setup
• One Time Tear Down
Parent Class : Base Class
• No TestFixture
• Set Up
o Driver initialization
• Tear Down
o Driver Quit
Child Class1:Parent Class
• Test Fixture
• Test Method
o Getting the driver instance from Parent class and testing the application
Child Class2:Parent Class
• Test Fixture
• Test Method
o Getting the driver instance from Parent class and testing the application

Comment: Sorry, your last comment (the "structure") isn't legible. Comments are limited. You should either edit the question or start a new question about trying to use a non-inherited setupfixture. Alternatively, post a question at the nunit framework project.

Comment: Hi @Charlie., Edited my questions and added the updated project structure as per your suggestions. please let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks

Comment: You're still inheriting from the SetUpFixture (base class) although it's indirect now with Child <= Parent <= Base. SetUpFixtures should not be inherited from at all.

Comment: Yeah, @Charlie. But if I am not inheriting the Base class into the Parent class then the SetUpFixture code is not being called at all.

Comment: If that's so, then your SetUpFixture code isn't correct. Are you sure it isn't being called? For example, have you set a breakpoint? It's possible that it's being called but is not having the effect you want. Can you post the non-inherited code of a setup fixture?

Comment: Hi @Charlie. Yes, I did put the breakpoint as well but it is not being called. I have added the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Are you sure the SetUpFixture class is either in the proper namespace or outside of all namespaces?